# Conseguir el valor mínimo PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta:

Tengo el siguiente código que determina la distancia entre 2 puntos usando Vincenty.

```
    <?php

//PUNTO 1
//Latitud
$grlat1=-37; //grados latitud punto 1
$minlat1=57; //minutos latitud punto 1
$seglat1=3.7203; //segundos latitud punto 1
//Longitud
$grlon1=144; //grados longitud punto 1
$minlon1=25; //minutos longitud punto 1
$seglon1=29.5244; //segundos longitud punto 1

//PUNTO 2
//Latitud
$grlat2=-37; //grados latitud punto 2
$minlat2=39; //minutos latitud punto 2
$seglat2=10.1561; //segundos latitud punto 2
//Longitud
$grlon2=143; //grados longitud punto 2
$minlon2=55; //minutos longitud punto 2
$seglon2=35.3839; //segundos longitud punto 2

//Transformación a grados decimales

//PUNTO 1
//Latitud
if($grlat1<0){

    global $latitud1;

    $latitud1=-(abs($grlat1)+$minlat1/60+$seglat1/3600);
} else{
    $latitud1=($grlat1+$minlat1/60+$seglat1/3600);
}
//Longitud
if($grlon1<0){

    global $longitud1;

    $longitud1=-(abs($grlon1)+$minlon1/60+$seglon1/3600);
} else{
    $longitud1=($grlon1+$minlon1/60+$seglon1/3600);
}

//PUNTO 2
//Latitud
if($grlat2<0){

    global $latitud2;

    $latitud2=-(abs($grlat2)+$minlat2/60+$seglat2/3600);
} else{
    $latitud2=($grlat2+$minlat2/60+$seglat2/3600);
}
//Longitud
if($grlon2<0){

    global $longitud2;

    $longitud2=-(abs($grlon2)+$minlon2/60+$seglon2/3600);
} else{
    $longitud2=($grlon2+$minlon2/60+$seglon2/3600);
}

function vincenty($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    // Radio ecuatorial
    $a = 6378137.0;
    //Radio polar
    $b = 6356752.31424518;
    //Aplastamiento del elipsoide
    $f = 0.00335281066;
    //Diferencia de longitud

    $radlat1 = ($lat1*pi()/180);
    $radlon1 = ($lon1*pi()/180);
    $radlat2 = ($lat2*pi()/180);
    $radlon2 = ($lon2*pi()/180);
    $L = ($radlon2) - ($radlon1);
    $U1 = atan((1 - $f) * tan($radlat1));  //U is 'reduced latitude'
    $U2 = atan((1 - $f) * tan($radlat2));
    $sinU1 = sin($U1);
    $sinU2 = sin($U2);
    $cosU1 = cos($U1);
    $cosU2 = cos($U2);
    $lambda = $L;
    $lambdaP = 2 * pi();
    $i = 20;

    while (abs($lambda - $lambdaP) > 1e-12 && --$i > 0) {
        $sinLambda = sin($lambda);
        $cosLambda = cos($lambda);
        $sinSigma = sqrt(($cosU2 * $sinLambda) * ($cosU2 * $sinLambda) + ($cosU1 * $sinU2 - $sinU1 * $cosU2 * $cosLambda) * ($cosU1 * $sinU2 - $sinU1 * $cosU2 * $cosLambda));

        if ($sinSigma == 0)
            return 0;  //Puntos coincidentes

        $cosSigma = $sinU1 * $sinU2 + $cosU1 * $cosU2 * $cosLambda;
        $sigma = atan2($sinSigma, $cosSigma);
        $sinAlpha = $cosU1 * $cosU2 * $sinLambda / $sinSigma;
        $cosSqAlpha = 1 - $sinAlpha * $sinAlpha;
        $cos2SigmaM = $cosSigma - 2 * $sinU1 * $sinU2 / $cosSqAlpha;
        if (is_nan($cos2SigmaM))
            $cos2SigmaM = 0;  //Linea ecuatorial: cosSqAlpha=0 (6)
        $c = $f / 16 * $cosSqAlpha * (4 + $f * (4 - 3 * $cosSqAlpha));
        $lambdaP = $lambda;
        $lambda = $L + (1 - $c) * $f * $sinAlpha * ($sigma + $c * $sinSigma * ($cos2SigmaM + $c * $cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * $cos2SigmaM * $cos2SigmaM)));
    }

    if ($i == 0)
        return false;  //La formula no pudo converger

    $uSq = $cosSqAlpha * ($a * $a - $b * $b) / ($b * $b);
    $A = 1 + $uSq / 16384 * (4096 + $uSq * (-768 + $uSq * (320 - 175 * $uSq)));
    $B = $uSq / 1024 * (256 + $uSq * (-128 + $uSq * (74 - 47 * $uSq)));
    $deltaSigma = $B * $sinSigma * ($cos2SigmaM + $B / 4 * ($cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * $cos2SigmaM * $cos2SigmaM) - $B / 6 * $cos2SigmaM * (-3 + 4 * $sinSigma * $sinSigma) * (-3 + 4 * $cos2SigmaM * $cos2SigmaM)));
    $d = $b * $A * ($sigma - $deltaSigma);
    return $d;

}

echo vincenty($latitud1,$longitud1,$latitud2,$longitud2) . "<br>";

?>
```

Como puedo traer de una BD MySQL los datos del PUNTO 2 Latitud y Longitud, los evalué la formula y me indique cual es la distancia menor entre todos esos puntos evaluados?

Es decir, el PUNTO 1 será introducido de manera manual pero el punto 2 que son estaciones debe ser traído desde una BD MySQL y evaluado por el código y que de todas las evaluaciones me indique cual es el valor mínimo.

Muchas gracias...

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado en relación a la base de datos? En tu código sólo se ven cálculos en PHP. ¿Has pensado en un modelo de datos? ¿Le has echado un vistazo a https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php ? Intenta algo y te ayudamos con gusto

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que lo puedes resolver de la siguiente manera:
La distancia del punto 1 y el punto 2(que sería el primer punto extraído de la base) guardarla como mínimo.
Una función que recibe dos distancia y te devuelve el mínimo de los dos, y guarda ese valor en la variable mínimo. Usa un bucle para calcular la distancia entre el numero de puntos que deseas.

```
minimo = distancia(punto1,punto2)
```

considerando que el punto2 es $i = 0, por eso i empezaria en 1

```
for($i=1; $i <= número de punto; $i++){

dist = distancia(punto1,punto[$i])
minimo = min(minimo, dist)
}

min(a,b){ si a>b retornar a, caso contrario retornar b}
```

Una desventaja seria si tienes que calcular la distancia de un punto con unos miles de puntos eso consumiria muchos recursos